# What structure do all kinds of theories, models, interpretations, proofs and all that form?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, foundations, type-theory, categorical-logic

This is a question about a structure that can be used to investigate all kind of structures that can be investigated. Many years ago with Joseph Gubeladze we discussed something similar but I only remember it was something more profound than what I am able to ask now.

I'm afraid I cannot say anything sensible about it. All I know is some amount of ($n$-)categorical semantics for type theories, which inspires some vague suggestions like writing down axioms for the relations between entities $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, ... with the semantical meanings like "$a$ is the theory of proofs of $b$ in $c$", or "$a$ is a description in $b$ of an interpretation of $c$ in $d$", or, in type-theoretic context, "$a$ is a term of type $b$ in the type theory $c$", or, in category-theoretic context, $a\in\hom_b(c,d)$, or $a=\hom_b(c,d)$, or ...

Did anyone write down such axioms and use them to study some properties of such "abstract theories"?

Comment: I don't have an exact reference, but in the spirit of what you are describing might be Martin Hyland's [Proof theory in the abstract](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~martin/Research/Publications/2002/pta02.pdf) and  [Categorical proof theory of classical propositional calculus](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82813535.pdf) by Bellin et al. These are rather specific, though.

Comment: @Andrej thank you! I definitely have to examine both. Besides, their specifics are akin to mine. But I gather there has been not much of a followup activity?

Comment: There was quite a bit of activity around categorical models of the Dialectica interpretation, but those focus on semantics, whereas you are asking about a category-theoretic framing of proof theory, as far as I understand.

Comment: @Andrej Yes, - more precisely (maybe I should add that to the question), mostly I am curious about category-like structures which would imitate an interpretation of one theory in another or constructing a model of one theory from a model of another theory. Something like this must be happening in Joyal's arithmetic universes which seemingly have internal categories imitating themselves but afaik this is still not published completely...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Could you perhaps check whether the answer below looks genuine?

Comment: @StefanKohl Yes it does, Joseph reminded me of some details of what we then discussed.

Answer (score -3):

მამუკა, მე როგორც მახსოვს, (მაგას "ბადეებს" ვეძახდით) ესეთი არაფორმალურ სურათი გვქონდა: ერთი სტრუქტურის/თეორიის... ა.შ. შესაბამისი ბადე იყო მეორე ბადეში ჩაქარგული. ამ ნაქარგში/ინტერპრეტაციაში ერეოდა მეორე ბადის თავისებურებები და თვისებები, რომლებიც უნდა განცალებული იქნას პირველწყაროს ნაქარგისგან. მნიშვნელოვანია სწორედ განიმარტოს ნაქარგების სიფაქიზის ზრდის მიმართულების ცნება, რომელიც გამოიწვევს პირველწყაროსადმი უფრო და უფრო ზუსტი მიახლოებების ცნებას.